# Pass results of Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync to Child Component

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am working on Outlook addin with pinnable taskpane. Everything works fine except I am stuck with passing the resulted `itemChanged` value, from `index.tsx` to `App.tsx` on each event trigger. Ideally i wouldn't want to implement Redux as it would be overkill. Any idea how to do that ? Below is my code:

index.tsx

```
let itemChanged = false;

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} **itemChanged ={itemChanged }** />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};
/* this is where the update happens but it is not trigering the update in App component
const itemChanged = eventArgs => {
  emailChanged = !emailChanged;
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.initialize = () => {
  isOfficeInitialized = true;

  // Set up ItemChanged event
  Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, itemChanged);

  render(App);
};
```

App.tsx

```
const App = (props: AppProps) => {
   const { title, isOfficeInitialized, **itemChanged ** } = props;
   return(/* router, appcontext etc */)
}
```

Comment: Is the task pane pinned? The `ItemChange` is fired when a task pane is pinned in the UI.

Comment: that is correct. The event in the sample code works ok.

Comment: It seems you don't have a pinned task pane at the time you subscribe to the event.

Comment: hmm. I am not entirely sure that this is a case. I do see event firing but my issue was on how to pass the received value to the component

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to utilise rxjs observables and send/subscribe on the email change within component